# How to create wallet for eos?

Tags: wallet

Hi i m new to EOS but not to Bitcoin and Etherum. I m looking a way to have an EOS Wallet but i don't know where i can do this.
I have bought some EOS on Binance exchange , for now, deposit and withdrawal are not possible. But when it will be possible i want to do that (withdrawal to a wallet)
I see everywhere, ERC-20 Token trought etherum but before 1st June 2018 .. but this date is passed.

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way is using cleos to create wallet, like Coutts said.

```
cleos wallet create
```

But this need some knowledge about how to create wallet, unlock/lock it, and how to import your EOS private key. [Here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Programs-&-Tools#cleos) is a start.

Comment: Where can i generate an eos private key?

Comment: use `cleos create key`.

Comment: I followed this following link https://eosnodes.privex.io/, after hours of errors . I finnaly was able to run nodeos cleos and kadeos. I created my wallet but i m stucking at the account part. I don’t have a generatedname from a previous account , as i said in my first post .